# DTS Connections Error

Tags: sql-server-2000, dts

I'm receiving this error while attempting to execute a package:

"The connection is currently being used by a task. The connection cannot be closed or reused."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with "Close Connection upon completion" under Workflow Properties. I ended up having to uncheck all of them to get this package to work.